# @RequestParam remove question mark in URL

Tags: spring, api, rest

I am trying to build a REST API with Spring.

How I can replace the URI

```
localhost: 8080 / rest / api / v1 / users / id ?id = 1
```

by

```
localhost: 8080 / rest / api / v1 / users / id / 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in solve the problem using @PathVariable , example :

```
public ResponseEntity<String> hello (@PathVariable Integer id) {

        String hello  ="hello "+ id ;
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(hello, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

and the corresponding URL is:

```
localhost:8080/hello/15
```

Tkx